# Ingress controller is not routing based on path in openshift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I am trying to configure ingress controller in openshift for one of my requirement. I need to route requests to different pods based on path. Found Ingress controller is suitable for my requirement. I have two services created and a ingress which routes to one of these services based on path. Here is my configuration. My app is in spring boot.

```
apiVersion: v1beta3
kind: List
items:
  -
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: data-service-1
      annotations:
        description: Exposes and load balances the data-indexer-service services
    spec:
      ports:
        -
          port: 7555
          targetPort: 7555
      selector:
        name: data-service-1
  -
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: data-service-2
      annotations:
        description: Exposes and load balances the data-indexer-service services
    spec:
      ports:
        -
          port: 7556
          targetPort: 7556
      selector:
        name: data-service-2
  -
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: data-service-2
    spec:
      host: doc.data.test.com
      port:
        targetPort: 7556
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: data-service-2
  -
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: entityreindexmap
  spec:
    rules:
      - host: doc.data.test.com
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /dbpath1
              backend:
                serviceName: data-service-1
                servicePort: 7555
            - path: /dbpath2
              backend:
                serviceName: data-service-2
                servicePort: 7556
```

I couldn't get this working. I tried with doc.data.test.com/dbpath1 and doc.data.test.com/dbpath2. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using both ``Route`` and ``Ingress`` at the same time for same host, it probably causes a conflict? Use one or the other. ``Route`` can also handle a prefix path, but you will need two differently named routes for same host but different prefix path.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton I tried removing the route configuration and kept only ingress. Ingress did not get created in this case. Btw, I am using openshift 3.9.x. Can you give an example of path based routing.

Comment: I think you might need a newer OpenShift version. Unless you have set up ingress controller yourself, it may not do anything for older OpenShift versions. In latest OpenShift version, OpenShift would under the covers map ingress to route for you. When you create an ingress, if you aren't see a corresponding route created to match, don't have new enough version for that. So suggest using path feature of route alone instead.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, that worked. I could create path based routes each pointing to different controllers(services). In my case, I have now 6 routes and 6 services. Is there a simpler way ? lets say 1 route controlling 6 services based on path ?

Comment: No, as far as I know routes aren't that flexible.